# How to remove subdirectory with nginx from urls using try_files

Tags: php, nginx, uri

The whole day I try to find a solution for the specific problem.

My structure looks like these:

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
}
```

Now all php-files of a subdirectory should be parsed in /index.php as well.

```
location /subdir/ {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
}
```

When I click `/subdir/thread.php?t=123` then `$uri` contains `/subdir/thread.php?t=123`. But I would like to have only `/thread.php?t=123` in `$uri` (without subdir).

Is this possible? I don't want to use rewrites because I use this script for a redirect script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression to capture the part of the `URI` to be passed to `/index.php`. Use either `location` or `rewrite` to achieve this.

Using a *regular expression* `location`:

```
location ~ ^/subdir(/.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$1&$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ { ... }
```

The *regular expression* `location` blocks are evaluated in order, so the position of the block within your configuration file is significant.

To send `.php` files within the subdirectory to `/index.php` you will need to place this `location` block **above** the `location \.php$` block.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

---

Using a named `location` with a `rewrite`:

```
location ^~ /subdir/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ~/subdir(/.*)$ /index.php?$1 last;
}
```

The `^~` operator ensures that `.php` files within the subdirectory are also sent to `/index.php`.

`rewrite` automatically appends the original query string. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: This works for static files. But in the subdir I have also PHP-Files. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Yeah, I missed that point. I have updated both solutions to cover `.php` files within the subdirectory.